Use Intune to set systemlocale = Entra ID country (Without loading Microsoft Graph)
With Intune, I would like to change the SystemLocale on all user PCs so that it matches the country associated with the user in Entra ID (Without loading Microsoft Graph)
I have tried to set the systemlocale with "Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale da-DK" but i struggle with getting the Entra ID user country
